# How do I create a create and call a vibration class in android?

Tags: java, android, class, android-vibration

Hi I want to call a vibration class throughout my android activities. Can someone please point me in the right direction? This is my vib class so far:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Vibrate {
    Vibrator vibs = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void vib(int length) {
        vibs.vibrate(length);
    }
}
```

and I want to call this guy from one of my activities like this:

```
Vibrate vib = new Vibrate();
...
vib.vib(500);
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: getSystemService is a method from the Context class. you need to call it on a context. (tip: an activity is a context).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class Vibrate {

    private Context mContext;
    private Vibrator mVibrator;

    public Vibrate(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mVibrator = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    }

    public void vib(int length) {
        mVibrator.vibrate(length);
    }
}

Vibrate vib = new Vibrate(this);
```

But I don't know why do you need such a class if `Vibrator` should be enough.